# Error while writing spec for ngFor with async pipe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Getting the error while writing the spec Since there is a *ngFor with async pipe in .html file

spec file:

```
describe('AaFinishReviewModalComponent', () => {
  let component: AaFinishReviewModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AaFinishReviewModalComponent>;
  let translate: TranslateService;
  const mockIuser: IUser = {
    Email: 'abc@xyzz.com',
  };
  const mockModalRef = {
    data: {
      finishReviewActionItems: of([
        {
          "name": "Approved",
          "nameKey": "Approved",
          "optionHintKey": "ApprovedHint",
          "optionHint": "Approving an assessment"
        },
      ])
    },
    destroy: jasmine.createSpy(),
  };
const mockDetailApi = jasmine.createSpyObj<AssessmentDetailApiService>(
    'AssessmentDetailApiService',
    ['isSendAssessmentUponApprovalRuleSet', 'getCompletedAssessmentActionItems']
  );
  
  const mockUserService = {
    isCurrentUser$: of(mockIuser),
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CoreTestingModule,
        CommonModule,
        VtModalModule,
        ...
        FormsModule,
        VtSelectModule,
      ],
      declarations: [AaFinishReviewModalComponent],
      providers: [
        TranslateService,
        { provide: VT_MODAL_REF, useValue: mockModalRef },
        { provide: AssessmentDetailApiService, useValue: mockDetailApi },
        ...
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AaFinishReviewModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    // Tried to assign the response of the API `api/assessment-v2/assessment-results` to component.finishReviewActionItems 
    component.finishReviewActionItems = of([
      {
        "name": "Approved",
        "nameKey": "Approved",
        "optionHintKey": "ApprovedHint",
        "optionHint": "Approving an assessment"
      },
      {
        "name": "Rejected",
        "nameKey": "Rejected",
        "optionHintKey": "RejectedHint",
        "optionHint": "Rejecting an assessment"
      }
    ]);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
 });
```

And In my .html page there is a component called `vt-select`,

```
 <vt-select
            required
            [id]="'AAFinishReviewActionDropdown'"
            ot-auto-id="'AAFinishReviewActionDropdown'"
            [placeholder]="'SelectAResult' | translate"
            [value]="selectedReviewAction?.value"
            (selectionChange)="selectReviewAction($event)"
          >
            <vt-option *ngFor="let option of finishReviewActionItems | async; index as i" [value]="option.name">
              <div>
                {{ option.name | translate }}
              </div>
            </vt-option>
          </vt-select>
```

.ts file having the respective code for `vt-select`

```
export class AaFinishReviewModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ...
  finishReviewActionItems: Observable<IAssessmentFilterValueOption[]>;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.finishReviewActionItems = this.assessmentDetailApi.getCompletedAssessmentActionItems();
  }
...
}
```

where as **getCompletedAssessmentActionItems()** is defined in the service as

```
getCompletedAssessmentActionItems(): Observable<IAssessmentFilterValueOption[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<IAssessmentFilterValueOption[]>(
        'api/assessment-v2/assessment-results'
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError(
          this.aaResponseHandlerService.error(this.translateService.instant('ErrorFetchingFilters'))
        )
      );
  }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: what is mockDetailApi  ?

Comment: Hi @Andrei, it is a jasmineMock for the service, I have updated the question

Comment: do `mockDetailApi.getCompletedAssessmentActionItems.and.returnValue(of([the array you want to use in your logic]))` before the first `fixture.detectChanges()`. should be ok then

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, I think this is what I am forgetting most of the time, I reliased this is missing